# Material Modal unusual behaviour

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material, angular-material2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EptKS.jpg)I am using angular material, and the below code is in modal. The problem is whenever i am clicking on the **Cancel** button, the ***`getSelectedCommittees`*** is also getting executed.

```
<div fxLayout="direction" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
<button mat-button class="act-button outline modal-blue-outline" 
[mat-dialog-close]="getSelectedCommittees()">OK</button>
<button mat-button class="act-button outline modal-blue-outline" 
[mat-dialog-close]="true"> Cancel </button>
```

I cannot understand why this is happening. Can anybody help me on this??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please add more code, it seems that the method may get called from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<button mat-button class="act-button outline modal-blue-outline" 
[mat-dialog-close]="getSelectedCommittees()">OK</button>
```

By:

```
<button mat-button
    type="submit" 
    (click)="getSelectedCommittees()"
    class="act-button outline modal-blue-outline">
    OK
</button>
```

And you can close the dialog box in your **`getSelectedCommittes`** function:

```
getSelectedCommittess() {
    // Some code...

    this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Comment: But, the problem remains same.

Comment: On clicking of OK, the dialog box does not gets closed. On Cancel the dialog box gets closed, but the method gets executed

Comment: You have to close the dialog box in the `getSelectedCommittees()` function in your .ts file or add `[mat-dialog-close]="closed"` and change `closed` boolean in `getSelectedCommittees()` function

Comment: Have you use `onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }` line of code in your dialog component?

Comment: The modal's are all on a different .ts file

Comment: `  openWarningModal_Ok(data): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ActOkWarningModalComponent, {
      backdropClass: "cams-check-modal-backdrop",
      panelClass: "cams-check-modal-panel",
      disableClose: true,
      data: { message: data }
    });

    return dialogRef.close();

    }`

Comment: I am doing all those..but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **`[mat-dialog-close]="getSelectedCommittees()"`**.

Here is the alternative 
**HTML file**

```
<div fxLayout="direction" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
<button mat-button class="act-button outline modal-blue-outline" 
(click)="getSelectedCommittees()">OK</button>
<button mat-button class="act-button outline modal-blue-outline" 
[mat-dialog-close]="true"> Cancel </button>
```

**TS file**

```
getSelectedCommittess() {
    // Things you want to perform
    // etc etc 

    this.dialogRef.close(); // this method will close the dialog or model
                            // after your operations where dialogRef is 
                            // the name of your reference variable
  }
```

For reference
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

Comment: on clicking of CANCEL, the method is still getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

As the **[Official Dialog Doc](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogClose)** say,
 that **"Button that will close the current dialog"**.

And its an input property for the Dialog Component, as its given as `@Input('mat-dialog-close')`

`mat-dialog-close` will always close the dialog if it's clicked, no matter what value you assign to it. If you want to control closing logic do it with `(click)="seeIfCloseableOrNot()"`. 
`mat-dialog-close` is an attribute and it will perform its working on which its added, and the functionality of `mat-dialog-close` is to close dialog.

You can use the value assigned to `mat-dialog-close`, using `dialogRef.afterClosed()`

Also See : https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9298

 as attaching some method to `mat-dialog-close` will call it many time due to change detection.

[See Demo with multiple call of function associated with matDialogClose](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-example-kxna4s?file=app/app.component.ts)